# Property 'filterFormula' not valid in version 51.0

Tags: visual-workflow, process-automation

I m facing issue while deploying the flow. with below error
**Property 'filterFormula' not valid in version 51.0**

```
ISNEW() || ISCHANGED({!$Record.StageName}) ) && 
NOT({!$Record.IsClosed}) && 
( {!$Record.RecordType.DeveloperName}= 'New'
```

also, i tried other lower version then its deplyoed successfully but the formula criteria is vanished (version 49 n below) when tried with version 50 n above then failing.

any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm what type of formula you are using there so can confirm based on it

Comment: Thank you for Quick responce. I m using this formula Sai( ISNEW() || ISCHANGED({!$Record.StageName}) )&& NOT({!$Record.IsClosed}) && (
 {!$Record.RecordType.DeveloperName}= 'New' ) @SaiPraveenKakkirala

Comment: Are you able to deploy it after v51 i'e with v52?

Comment: i tried but no luck

Comment: is it failing with same error?

Answer (score 1):

`filterFormula` in Flow metadata [requires V55.0 or higher](https://filterFormula%09string%09A%20formula%20used%20to%20filter%20what%20records%20execute%20the%20flow%20during%20a%20save.%20Available%20only%20in%20record-triggered%20flows.%20Available%20in%20API%20version%2055.0%20and%20later.)

> filterFormula string
>
> A formula used to filter what records execute the flow during a save.
> Available only in record-triggered flows. Available in API version
> 55.0 and later.

Use V55 or higher in your deployment CI/CD pipeline/process. You will need the flow to run in at least V55 too.